# Google Plus Java Cli Starter export jar with Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, google-plus

I wrote an Application-Project in java and now i want to import the google plus java starter project(https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/)(slightly modified) to this Project. If i run it in eclipse all works fine, but if i export that project als runnable jar file all methods concerning this google plus java starter project are not able to run.
I thinkt this has to do with the maven dependencies, but i don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI starter is old, you should use the latest Google+ API samples from the GitHub page:

https://github.com/googleplus

Additional instructions for building and running the samples are available from the Google+ developer site:

https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart